# How can I level up my smithing really quick without the Oghma Infinium

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have just started out as an Orc and I wanted him to be a blacksmith so that I can create Heavy Armor.

Comment: If you're aiming to roleplay being a smith right away, use console commands to just give yourself the skill.

Comment: what are Console commands

Comment: [Console commands](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) article at UESP.

Comment: fortify restoration glitch. Not patched yet.